# When creating a higher order map function should I use a pointer or a reference or a value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following piece of code in C++:

```
  EventQueue * EventQueueNode::map(std::function<LoggerEvent *(LoggerEvent *)> func, 
                                   bool stop_propagate = true){
            auto old_node = this->event_node;
            this->event_node = func(this->event_node);
            delete old_node;
            return this->right()->map(func, stop_propagate);
    };
```

This code breaks if the user returns the same pointer, but if I don't delete it, it will leak memory.

EventQueue is a circular doubly linked list. And it has a head, which hold both ends, but which functions as endpoint:

```
    EventQueue * EventQueue::map(std::function<LoggerEvent *(LoggerEvent *)> func, 
                                 bool stop_propagate = false) {
            if(stop_propagate)
                    return this;

            return this->right()->map(func, true);

    };
```

Now I have a problem. I really would like to write the map function as:

```
  EventQueue * EventQueueNode::map(std::function<LoggerEvent(LoggerEvent)> func, 
                                   bool stop_propagate = true){

            this->event_node = func(this->event_node);
            return this->right()->map(func, stop_propagate);
    };
```

Because the previous map needs to be destructed anyway and it doesn't cause memory leaks. And a map traditionally replaces a value.  But then I also have to make event_node a value, which will cause it to be copied everywhere. I am quite a beginner, so I am getting stuck at the approach I should take.

What would be a good approach to tackle this problem?

Full code:

http://pastebin.com/NT1pD5ar (most code is in a construction state and there are more issues I have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use smart pointers like `shared_ptr<LoggerEvent>` to store it in containers and pass it around. The object that the smart pointer points to will be destroyed once all copies of the smart pointer are destroyed.

Comment: This sounds really interesting, c++ seems to evolve into a better language everytime I look at it. Since when are these in C++?

Comment: Well, the boost libraries had them for ages. And they were included in standard several years ago (at least they were supposed to).

Comment: The new standard also has more interesting things in it like "auto" variables (though these are easily abused) and "for each" loop support.

Comment: That some some sort of type interference? I am still searching for those kind of things. I have written some C++ on school and that was 10 years ago, so I am far behind. I need probably to buy a book.

Comment: Yes, something like this. (Assuming you meant "type inference". :) ) It spares programmer from specifying the variable type.